# Fail-over to secondary region when primary region goes down on a IBM MQ Multi-instance Queue manager using a NFS 4.1 share

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-mq

We've a Multi-instance IBM MQ queue manager setup in 2 regions in Azure , with an NFS 4.1 share(Azure Netapp files) holding the state cross-mounted between instances in 2 regions.

Let's say

- One VM in East
- Other VM in West
- Azure Neatpp Files NFS  4.1 share provisioned in East(Mounted on East VM and West VM) [ this holds MQ state ]

We're in a problematic situation for a failover scenario as we have a hard dependancy on NFS mount.

How can we achieve High availability/Resliency incase of a Azure Netapp Files failure , or a East region failure ?

Comment: Look at RDQM instead of MI.

Comment: We've licensing limitations and are trying to circumvent this problem.